# Using window.location.pathname.split() in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using this window.location.pathname.split() to split a path name inorder to get a specific id from this url: basically I'm trying to get the /image/**1** the id right after the "/image/". I know it's simple and I'm close I just cant seem to get to it. I used two approaches to get with no luck.

http://localhost:4200/image/1;id=1;catergory=testing.

```js
(3) ["/image/1", "id=1", "catergory=testing"]
0
:
"/image/1"
1
:
"id=1"
2
:
"catergory=testing"
length
:
3
_proto_
:
Array(0)
```

```js
(3) ["", "image", "1;id=1;catergory=testing"]
0
:
""
1
:
"image"
2
:
"1;id=1;catergory=testing"
length
:
3
_proto_
:
Array(0)
```

```js
    this.route.params.subscribe(response => {
       let path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
       let path1 = window.location.pathname.split(';')
       const id = path[0]
       console.log("Path",path)
       console.log("Path",path1)
       console.log("id", id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

```
window.location.pathname.split(";")[0].split("/").pop()
```

Explanation:

```
window.location.pathname.split(";")
```

would return:

```
["http://localhost:4200/image/1", "id=1", "catergory=testing"]
```

Get the first item in the array with [0] and split it by "/":

```
window.location.pathname.split(";")[0].split("/")
```

It would return

```
["http:", "", "localhost:4200", "image", "1"]
```

Get the last element with pop() or however you desire.

But as nanabyte said above, using angular router is the preferred way to do this.

Comment: His approach makes sense to me but when I add another parameter to the route, I don't get the correct id number that I want. I explain what happens under his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Angular Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router). This will allow you to easily get route parameters.

**Configure Router**

*app.module.ts*

```
...
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
...

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'image/:imageId', component: ImageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*Note the `:imageId` parameter specified in the route.*

**Add Router Outlet**

Add this to the component where you want to display content. E.g. *app.component.html*

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Get the ID**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Data} from '@angular/router';

...

export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const imageId = this.route.snapshot.params['imageId'];
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment.

Comment: That works if I have a route that goes like that <a [routerLink] = "['/image', image.id]"> it gets the images id. However, if I add another parameter that passes through the route it returns the second parameters id number for example if I had <a [routerLink] = "['/image', image.id]", domain>, domain is an array that consists of an domain.id and domain.catergory. It always returns that domain.id. When I actually want to get the images id number.

Comment: Can you provide me examples of the URLs you see in the address bar in browser?

Comment: That's what my url looks like in the browser.

Comment: localhost:4200/image/2;id=1;catergory=testing

Comment: The variable name for image id cannot be the same and the domain id. I.e. update to `{ path: 'image/:imageId', component: ImageComponent }` and `const imageId = this.route.snapshot.params['imageId'];`. I've updated answer.

Comment: It says it returns undefined.

Comment: I've created an example on stackblitz that successfully gets the correct id from parameter. [Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i8r5xh?embed=1&file=app/image.component.ts) & [Demo](https://angular-i8r5xh.stackblitz.io/image/2;id=1;catergory=testing)

Comment: Can you make a chat. I just want to clarify a few things. I understand the code and everything but I think I might have a little issue applying it to my scenario

Comment: If you create a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) showing the issue you're having i'd be happy to have a look.

Comment: This is the editors link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxej32 how do you make a demo?

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm still get undefined is it because i'm using a service?